# Django migration from Foreign key to Integer field error occured

Tags: django, django-models

I'm facing an issue migrating my django models, when converting the foreign key to normal integer field.
Here you are my code below.

```
Old migration data type:
bank_id = models.ForeignKey(Bank, related_name='bank', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True,null=True)

New migration data type:
bank = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)


**The error that I got from the migration.
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''**
```

Any idea, how I can convert the existing data in the table?

Comment: well, did you check your data? since you allowed ```blank=True,null=True```it almost sounds to me like you have a blank and or a null value in your table...

Comment: @Tomek- Confirmed there is no NULL or Blank data, but all foreign keys.

Comment: what about the other table? The error looks to me it tries to convert ```''``` to ```int```